# How does Katalon Studio detect a custom Keyword?

Tags: katalon-studio

Typically, one would create custom keywords using the Katalon Studio GUI as described in the [docs](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-to-custom-keywords.html): create a package, store classes in the package and have keyword actions (methods) marked as `@keyword`.

Since we want to push Katalon Studio to find its boundaries, I've created a package in a groovy file, defined a class and added `@keyword` to its methods, then put it in the `/Keywords` folder.

I am now able to call those keywords, and confirmed that each keyword was successfully added to the `Libs/CustomKeywords.groovy` file after a project refresh.

Instead, if I add keywords in a file located elsewhere, for instance in the `/Include` folders, they are not added to `Libs/CustomKeywords.groovy`. Is it safe to assume that Katalon Studio will only import keywords from the `/Keywords` folder and, eventually, [.jar libraries](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/external-libraries.html#using-gradle)?

Comment: There is an option to import a custom keyword as a plugin https://forum.katalon.com/t/katalon-plugin-keywords-are-not-coming-under-custom-keywords/29029, but I haven't used it so I cannot tell you more about it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm experimenting various import methods, but for now I'm bounded not to use external plugins. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/Include` folder is where Katalon will check for its BDD files. So, if in `/Include/features` there is a feature file with some defined steps, Katalon will search `/Include/scripts` for step definition files.

> Each Gherkin step in the Features file needs to be defined as a set of programming code so that the machine can execute the actions of these steps. These Step Definitions can be implemented in Keyword folder by leveraging the Script Mode. Katalon Studio built-in keywords can also be re-used in step definition files as well. When Katalon Studio executes any Features files in the test case, it will also look for the matching step definitions in the source folder.

[Source.](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/cucumber-features-file.html)

This part

> These Step Definitions can be implemented in Keyword folder by leveraging the Script Mode.

may sound confusing, but it is basically saying step definitions can include custom keywords from `/Keyword` folder.

That's why I wouldn't put other custom keywords there.

Another place you can put custom code is `/Test Listeners` section. That will hold code for [SetUp() and TearDown()](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/fixtures-listeners.html#setup-and-teardown-for-test-suite-and-test-case) methods for Test Suites and Test Cases.

Comment: So anything inherits from /Keywords, because the list of custom keywords is updated based on the content of that folder. Any `keyword` definition elsewhere is not added to the list and won't be accessible. Yeah, the include folder is really confusing